# How do I calculate one input with realtime summation of other input in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text" name="item_price[]" onblur="findTotal()" />
<input type="text" name="pay" id="pay" >
```

Javascript:

```
function findTotal()
{
    var items=document.getElementsByName('item_price[]');
    var payment=document.getElementsById('pay');

    var sum =0;
    for(key=0; key < items.length; key++)  
    {
        sum += Number(items[key].value) ;
        document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
    }
    var pay = Number(payment);
    document.getElementById('due').value = sum-pay;
}
```

Output :

```
<input class="form-control"  type="text"  name="total" id="total" >
<input class="form-control" type="text"  name="due" id="due">
```

Here total amount could be shown . But due field could not work. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to use `var payment = document.getElementById('pay')` and `var pay = Number(payment.value)`?

Comment: where are the elements with ids of `total` and `due`

Comment: Is there supposed to be one `pay` field or multiple `pay` fields?  Looks like you might have wanted to write `payment = document.getElementById('pay').value`

Comment: There is one pay field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function findTotal()
  {
     var names=document.getElementsByName('item_quantity[]');
     var rates=document.getElementsByName('item_rate[]');

     var payments=document.getElementsByName('pay');
     var num = Number(payments);

     var sum =0;
     for(key=0; key<names.length; key++)  
     {
        sum += Number(names[key].value)*Number(rates[key].value) ;
        document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
     }    
 }


$('input').keyup(function()
{ 
    var firstValue  = Number($('#pay').val()); 
    var secondValue  = Number($('#total').val()); 

    $('#due').html(firstValue + 1000); 
    document.getElementById('due').value = secondValue-firstValue;

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `payment` variable contains a NodeList (a list of HTML elements), so it can't really be converted to a number.

Get the first element of the list, and convert to number the value of it:

```
var pay = Number(payment[0].value);
```

Alternatively, you can select the element via `.getElementById`, which returns a single element, but you'll still have to get the value:

```
var payment = document.getElementById('pay');
```

and

```
var pay = Number(payment.value);
```

And to make the thing really real-time, use the `oninput` event instead of `onblur` on your input fields:

```js
function findTotal() {
  var items = document.getElementsByName('item_price[]');
  var payment = document.getElementById('pay');

  var sum = 0;
  for (key = 0; key < items.length; key++) {
    sum += Number(items[key].value);
    document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
  }
  var pay = Number(payment.value);
  document.getElementById('due').value = sum - pay;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="item_price[]" oninput="findTotal()" /><br>
<input type="text" name="item_price[]" oninput="findTotal()" /><br>
<input type="text" name="item_price[]" oninput="findTotal()" /><br>
<input type="text" name="pay" id="pay" oninput="findTotal()" ><br>
<br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="total" id="total" ><br>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="due" id="due" ><br>
```

Comment: Brother, pay input having only one element. Not an array.

Comment: `payment` **is** an array:  it was the result of `getElementsByName('pay')`  `getElements...` with an 's'.

Comment: @rashedcs It is a list containing a single element, since it was selected by `.getElementsByName`, and it always returns a list.

Comment: Consider pay as an element . not a list or array.

Comment: consider `2` as `3`! There is no 'consider' in programming!

Comment: @rashedcs You might consider anything as anything else, but JavaScript (or any other programming language) won't do that. You can decide whether you program a computer as it require, or to not program it. No other options. You could try your ways as well, but don't be surprised if it doesn't work as you expect. `.getElementsByName` does return a list. If you don't like that fact, don't use that method.

Comment: I have modified it, pay called through getElementsById. I think it makes clear that pay is one filed, not multiple . And it is not used as list or array.

Comment: @rashedcs `.getElementById` really returns a single element, as IDs should be unique, while names aren't, so using it is a good solution as well. **Note:** `.getElementsById` is really `.getElementById` (no `s`)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".item_price");
let tot = document.querySelector("#total");

function findTotal()
{
    let int
    let sum = [...items].reduce((acc,cur) => {
        int = parseInt(cur.value, 10)
        return acc + (int ? int : 0)
    },0)
    tot.value = sum
}
```

```html
Cost: <input type="text" class="item_price" name="item_price[]" onblur="findTotal()" /><br>
Cost: <input type="text" class="item_price" name="item_price[]" onblur="findTotal()" /><br>
Cost: <input type="text" class="item_price" name="item_price[]" onblur="findTotal()" /><br>
Total: <input type="text" name="total" id="total" >
```

Comment: I don't think it was necessary to drastically change how it was done.  (e.g.: `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByName`; `reduce` instead of `for` loop; etc.) 
 The question is rooted on a simple mistake and it's not really worth providing a better implementation.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```js
function findTotal()
{
    var items=document.querySelectorAll('.item_price');
    var payment=document.getElementById('pay');
    var total=0;

    for (let item of items) {
     total += parseFloat(item.value) || 0 // || 0 in case other inputs not yet have a value
    }
    
  document.getElementById('due').value = total;   
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="item_price[]" class="item_price" onblur="findTotal()" />
<input type="text" name="pay" id="pay" >
<input type="text" name="pay" id="due" >
```